# Using sockets on Openshift

Tags: python, ios, sockets, openshift

I created a python script to manage a group chat application I am writing for iOS. The script uses sockets to send a string of text (from a list), that is interpreted in my ios app to populate and array to be displayed in a uitableview. For other people to connect with it, I decided to use OpenShift, and I ran into a problem. I can run the script ok using action hooks, but I need to connect my client (ios app), to my server (script on openshift). How would I get an IP and port from openshift to connect my client to?

TL;DR: Wrote a python script to manage an iphone chat app using sockets. Uploaded it to openshift, but can't get the ip/port to connect to it.

Comment: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/203263674-What-external-ports-are-available-on-OpenShift-

Comment: @mbaird What would I use to get the IP?

Comment: There are some environment variables with lot of the config, see the [openshift's help](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html)

Comment: So would I get the ip from OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP and port from OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT ? Also, how will I send the data to this ip from my ios app?

Comment: You need to send data to your application using your application url (app-domain.rhcloud.com) and use port 8000 (or port 8443 for secure web sockets)

Comment: And my server script listens on port 8080 or OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT